# After add implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0 app running error

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, admob, android-studio-3.0

After I add implementation **com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0** app running error. Here is the code

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: what is the error you see

Comment: After added implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0 i face unfortunately app has stopped . If i removed the code implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0 Then app running well

Answer (score 1):

Below step is required as of `Google Mobile Ads SDK` version `17.0.0`.   You can check release note [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes).

> Failure to add below  tag results in a crash with the
>   message: "The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly."

---

Update your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Add your AdMob App ID to your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file by adding the  tag shown below. You can find your App ID in the AdMob UI. For android:value insert your own AdMob App ID in quotes, as shown below.

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```